# Difference between Dynamic Programming and Divide and Conquer

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

What is the main difference between divide and conquer and dynamic programming? If we take an example merge sort is basically solved by divide and conquer which uses recursion . Dynamic programming is also based on recursion than why not Merge sort considered to be an example of dynamic programming?

Answer (score 9):

The two are similar in that they both break up the problem into small problems and solve those. However, in divide and conquer, the subproblems are independent, while in dynamic programming, the subproblems are dependent. Both requiring recombining the subproblems in some way, but the distinction comes from whether or not the subproblems relate to other subproblems (of the same "level")

D&C example: **Mergesort**

In Mergesort, you break the sorting into a lot of little "sub-sorts", that is instead of sorting 100 items, you sort 50, then 25, etc. However, after breaking the original into (for example) 4 "sub-sorts", it doesn't matter which you do first; order is irrelevant because they are independent. All that matter is that they eventually get done. As such, each time, you get an entirely independent problem with its own right answer.

DP example: **Recursive Fibonacci**

Though there are sub-problems, each is directly built on top of the other. If you want the 10th digit, you have to the solve the problems building up to that (1+2, 2+3, etc) in a specific order. As such, they are not independent.

Comment: Like in fibonacci numbers the next output depends on previous ones so we call it dependent sequence. But can't we say this in case of merge sort ? Like when comparing the numbers and then  merging the partitions ?

Comment: Every problem that can be solved, can be solved using recursion. D&C is just recursion where you split the problems into independent *peer* subproblems. DP is just recursion where you *reuse solutions to some subproblems multiple times*. For this to be possible, the problem must have 2 properties called optimal substructure and overlapping subproblems.

Comment: could one say though that dynamic programming encapsulates d&c? Just because DP makes use of overlapping problems doesn't mean that they need to overlap right? It would be no worse time wise than d&c but (likely) much worse space wise.  But if I'm not worried about space this is ok right?

Comment: @IanPanzica mmm I don't know if I'd call it encapsulation. Maybe "inheritance" is an apt discription (DP inherits from D&C). I'm not quite sure what your question is. If its "must they overlap?", building upon the previous solution is what makes DP, DP. I think that's what you mean by "overlap". If its "is DP as fast as D&C?", I would they they're generally the same-ish. It would depend on the algorithms since DP and D&C are just concepts but overall they can both be quick.

Comment: Here's a more succinct statement along what I was asking: Algorithmic solutions provided by the dynamic programming paradigm properly contain
algorithmic solutions provided by the divide and conquer paradigm.  Would this be true?

Comment: @IanPanzica IMHO, no. Though they are very similar processes, that subtle difference is a big deal. There are probably plenty of problems that can be solved with either but they are distinct (albeit closely related) concepts.

Comment: Ok so I would feel comfortable saying that (and this may be repetitive) the distinction is in how you split the problem up.  D&C can do this in any way that produces independent subproblems but DP needs to know something about how the problems relate in order to iteratively build up some sort of solution.

Comment: @IanPanzica yeah that's accurate

Answer (score 0):

D&C is used when sub-problems are independent. Dynamic programming needed when a recursive function repeats same recursive calls.

Take fibonacci recurrence:  f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)

For example:

f(8) = f(7) + f(6) 
= ( f(6) + f(5) ) + f(6)

As you can see f(6) will be calculated twice.  From the recurrence relation, obviously there are too many repeating values. It's better to memorize these values rather than calculating over and over again. Most important thing in dp is memorizing these calculated values. If you look at dp problems generally an array or a matrix is used for preventing repetitive calculations.

Comparing to dp, d&c generally divides problem into independent sub-problems and memorizing any value is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So I would say that D&C is a bigger concept and DP is special kind of D&C. Specifically, when you found that your subproblems need to share some calculations of same smaller subproblem, you may not want them to calculate the same things again and again, you cache the intermediate results to speed up time, that comes the DP. So, essentially, I would way, DP is a fast version of D&C.